# Drive images backup in Linux

Tags: linux, backup, disk-image, snapshot

I have a linux server, and i want to make an image of the whole drive in real-time, like acronis does.

Comment: could you further explain 'wants in a real time.'? W/ linux, you can literally just do a `dd` on the /dev/hdX and get an image of the hard drive. Very easy to do and very easy to put back (just change the if and of options around basically)

Comment: yeah, I wasn't sure you could do that with an in use root partition.  i think in real time means without going to alternate boot media

Comment: You can do that with an in use root partition, but dd'ing **RW mounted filesystems**  might not result in an accurate result. If you can boot in RO mode then it is a working option.

Answer (score 3):

I use LVM religiously.  It makes filesystem management so much easier...if you use lvm there's a tutorial here: http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_snapshots

Answer (score 3):

LVM is a good choice.

LVM snapshot can be created in real time by -s when using [lvcreate](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-lvcreate/#lbAE). For example, we can create a 2GB snapshot of lv_root by:

```
# lvcreate -L20480 -s -n 'lv_root_snapshot' /dev/vg/lv_root
```

Then we can dd the snapshot out (this cost time):

```
# dd if=/dev/vg/lv_root_snapshot of=/var/backup/lv_root.img
```